# Launch a java action when VLC closes

Tags: java, external, vlc

Im making a TV-serie bookmark application in Java.

My question is: how do I make my application listen to an external program and fire an action when that program is closed by the user? In my case, when I close VLC I want my java-app to run some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd need to work out how to write a plugin to VLC.